# Render different CSS when page is accessed from different domain

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, themes

I have ASP.NET MVC app.
I want to run a single instance of my app.
Two different domains would point to the app.
I want to apply different CSS for each one of them.
So that app_name_1.com would use different CSS to app_name_1.com.

I wanted to create two bundles of styles and in my layout page check from where the request is coming and then render different bundle based on that.

I'm wondering whether this would work.
Is there any different approach to solve this?

Comment: I'd recommend doing this with a login step instead. Each user gets assigned one or the other styles, then you are assured of it being correct. A user using a VPN could thwart your location-based system, for example.

Comment: I want to apply different styles to login page as well, therefore I need use different styles before user logs in, also some parts of the page are available to view without the new to login.

Comment: Why do you want the app to look different to different users?

Comment: One of the portals is for VIP users, I want them to experience a rich UI, the other is standard. I need two different domains though.

Comment: You can run different css files on each domain, pretty simple. :)

Comment: are you thinking of using javascript to load them? I'm not convinced of that.